# iOS 11: Media Player crash

Tags: ios, ios11

Starting with iOS 11, I've been seeing this crash:

```
1 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_sync_wait + 63192 
2 MediaToolbox videoQueueRemote_Invalidate + 5984376 
3 MediaToolbox videoQueueRemote_Invalidate + 5984376 
4 MediaToolbox videoQueueRemote_Finalize + 5984828  
5 CoreMedia FigBaseObjectFinalize + 47300  
6 CoreFoundation _CFRelease + 963176  
7 AVFoundation -[AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer dealloc] + 1467352  
8 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit() + 745496  
9 MediaToolbox FigLayerSynchronizerSynchronizeToMoment + 857340  
10 MediaToolbox videoQueueRemote_SynchronizeLayerToMoment + 5994476  
11 MediaToolbox figSyncMomentSource_sendMomentInternal + 852744  
12 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout + 6404  
13 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 46184  
14 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 48632  
15 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 51244  
16 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 84560  
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_wqthread + 4680
```

Just wanted to understand if this is an issue with my app or if this is apple BETA issue.

Note: The issue is intermittent.

Comment: Seeing a similar crash throughout iOS 11 versions. Did you pinpoint a cause for this?

Comment: In my case, I was seeing this crash as I was deallocating AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer after it was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the Media Player framework but my guess is you use `AVPlayer` for video playback since the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer) states

> To enable users to play videos containing MPMediaItem objects, use
>   AVPlayer. You cannot play video media items using the Media Player
>   framework.

If so, you probably use `AVPlayerLayer` for display which is very likely to employ an `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` internally. Which would be the one from your stack trace:

> 7 AVFoundation -[AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer dealloc] + 1467352

I got the same crash and saw the same stack trace on a background thread while working directly with `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`. After lots of debugging and testing I found that moving all the code that touches this layer to the main thread got rid of the crash. The `viewWill...` and `viewDid...` callbacks are good places for the setup:

```
var player : AVPlayer!
var layer : AVPlayerLayer!
// var layer : AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer! // in my case

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    // self.layer = AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer() // in my case
    self.layer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.layer)
}
```

The same is true for `enqueue(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer)` and `flush()` or `flushAndRemoveImage()` when working with `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`.

Comment: Thanks @bfx. In my case, I was using an external video player library. Removing all player layers before I instantiate a new instance helped.